# CollectionView Not Rendering

Tags: ios, swift

So I have two different CollectionViews which are rendered in my controller like so.

```
private func configure(){
        print("Enter configure function")
        func configureViews(){
//takes previously created dynamoCollectionView and assigns it to and creates an instance of DynamoCollectionView
            //init for bottom dynamoCollectionView
            self.dynamoCollectionView = DynamoCollectionView(frame: .zero)
            //init for top dynamoCollectionView
            self.dynamoCollectionViewTop = DynamoCollectionViewTop(frame: .zero)
            //A Boolean value that determines whether the view’s autoresizing mask is translated into Auto Layout constraints.
            self.dynamoCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.dynamoCollectionViewTop.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            //will allow you to supply your own data to the bottom collectionView
            self.dynamoCollectionView.dataSource = self
            //will allow you to send messages about interaction with the bottom dynamoCollectionView to self
            self.dynamoCollectionView.delegate = self

            //will allow you to supply your own data to the top collectionView
            self.dynamoCollectionViewTop.dataSourceTop = self
            //will allow you to send messages about interaction with the top dynamoCollectionView to self
            self.dynamoCollectionViewTop.delegateTop = self

            self.dynamoCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white
            self.dynamoCollectionViewTop.backgroundColor = .white

            self.view.backgroundColor = .white
            self.view.addSubview(self.dynamoCollectionView)
            self.view.addSubview(self.dynamoCollectionViewTop)



            NSLayoutConstraint.activateViewConstraints(self.dynamoCollectionView, inSuperView: self.view, withLeading: 0.0, trailing: 0.0, top: nil, bottom: nil, width: nil, height: nil)
            _ = NSLayoutConstraint.activateVerticalSpacingConstraint(withFirstView: self.topLayoutGuide, secondView: self.dynamoCollectionView, andSeparation: 0.0)
            _ = NSLayoutConstraint.activateVerticalSpacingConstraint(withFirstView: self.dynamoCollectionView, secondView: self.bottomLayoutGuide, andSeparation: 0.0)
        }
        //goes here first
        configureViews()
    }
```

The first collectionView is the dynamoCollectionViewTop. I want that to render above the dynamoCollectionView but it seems to not be rendered at all. I tried mimicking the constraints and making the appropriate changes but it does not seem to be rendering. How would the constraints look to properly render this.

My screen currently looks like this
[image]

The white space should be the top collectionView

Answer (score 0):

Add these constraints for **dynamoCollectionView**

```
    dynamoCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

    dynamoCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true 

    dynamoCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Add these constraints for **dynamoCollectionViewTop**

```
  dynamoCollectionViewTop.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true


  dynamoCollectionViewTop.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true


  dynamoCollectionViewTop.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dynamoCollectionView.topAnchor).isActive = true 

  dynamoCollectionViewTop.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true

  dynamoCollectionViewTop.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

Comment: Cannot invoke 'constraint' with an argument list of type '(equalTo: UILayoutSupport)' get this error for the last constrint

Comment: are you there @Sh_Khan